# Capture string key with terminfo in C program

Tags: c, ncurses, terminfo

Nobody know a good way to take the terminfo key string in a C program? Like the infocmp of ncurses. I can't find anything :(

If someone know and want to tell me, I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

"Capturing" the value depends on what you are trying to do with it.  The usual application uses the [`tigetstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html) function to read the value for a given terminal *capability* from the terminal database.

To do this, you must first initialize the terminfo interface using the ncurses library, for example using [`setupterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_terminfo.3x.html), `setterm` or [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html).  The choice of function depends on what the program will be doing with the string.

In [ncurses-examples](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html), there are a few low-level terminal programs such as `demo_terminfo`.